# Many Class Library and need only one to load in a project -C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program that is having 3 class library file in a project.

After loading a class library, return it to my project and use the selected library for the rest of the project.

It's like a configuration project. - C#

```
    Using MyRef; //Class1
    Using NewRef; //Class2
    Using RevisionRef; //Class3
    public static string mChoose { get; set; }
    public String Myconfiguration(string pActivity)
    {
        string _retval = "";
        if (pActivity== "class1")
        { 
            Class1 _class1 = new Class1();
            _retval = _class1;
        }
        else if (pActivity== "class2")
        { 
            Class2 _class2 = new Class2();
            _retval = _class2;
        }
        else if(pActivity== "class3")
        { 
            Class3 _class3 = new Class3();
            _retval = _class3;
        }
        return _retval;
    }
```

Comment: Just add a reference to the project that you want to use.

Comment: its not a stable project. example for this month I'll use the first library and next month I'll choose the second library. is it possible?

Comment: you have everything inside.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to achieve versioning of assemblies you are using. I would look into `Nuget` packages to achieve that.

Comment: [Seems to me that you are explaining X instead of Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you add more details to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your class names are wrong eg Class1 should be of type MyRef also you can't just assign an object to a string eg _retval = _class1;
If you want to return a class the whole method will have to be rewritten to return an object of whatever class you decide to create.
You probably want something like this:

```
switch (pActivity)
{
    case "class1":
        MyRef _class1 = new MyRef();
                break;
    case "class2":
        NewRef _class2 = new NewRef();
        break;
    case "class3":
        RevisionRef _class3 = new RevisionRef();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

then whichever class is created will have all the methods of that class type.

Comment: When I return it as an Object, can I use all the methods/function inside the object?